# New line using JLabel and java variable from ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jframe, jlabel

I create a button that will onclick show in a separate window (like you see below) the list of all users from my database.

But, they are displayed all in one line! Even though I put /n - it just wont work. I mean, it work in console when I use Sys.out but when I go to the Window and put it there it is all in one line :(

What should I change in order to display all of the users one below another.

```
public class ViewAll {
    private String listax = "";

        ViewAll() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException{

        ArrayList<String[]> allUsers = DbBroker.getArray("select * from user");
                for(String[] usr : allUsers)
                    listax += usr[0] + ")" + usr[1] + ", " + usr[2] + ", " + usr[3] + "\n";
        }

    public void display() {
        JFrame lis = new JFrame("List of all users");
        lis.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        lis.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        lis.add(pane);
        pane.add(new JLabel("This is the complete list of all users in my db: "));
        pane.add(new JLabel(listax));

        lis.pack();
        lis.setSize(500,400);
        lis.setVisible(true);
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you don't use a JLabel but instead use a JList. It was built to do just this sort of a thing. The key here being: use the right tool for the job. It also appears that you're trying to use a JFrame in a dialog capacity, and if so, don't -- use a JDialog instead, or even a JOptionPane:

```
public void display(List<String> userList) {
  DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
  for (String user : userList) {
    listModel.addElement(user);
  }
  JList<String> userLabel = new JList<String>(listModel);
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(userLabel);

  String title = "This is the complete list of all users in my db:";

  // mainJFrame is the main JFrame for the GUI
  JOptionPane.showMessageOption(mainJFrame, scrollPane, title, 
       JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);  
}
```